# Methods in Activity A are calling in Activity B while Activity A is finished

Tags: java, android

I know it's weird but I've faced with this problem today. I developed several applications but I have never seen anything like this.
Let me explain more; I have a class which is the parent of all Activities. I named it ActivityEnhanced.

```
public class ActivityEnhanced extends AppCompatActivity implements INetConnection.Callback{

    public static INetConnection mNetWork;
    private static DataPacket dataPacket;


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        G.setCurrentActivity(this);

        if(dataPacket == null){
            dataPacket = new DataPacket();
        }

        if(mNetWork == null){
            mNetWork = new INetConnection(this);
            mNetWork.connectToNetwork();
        }
    }
    .....
    .
    .
    public void sectionRequestDone() {}
}
```

I have two children Activities A and B, I want to login to activity B when I receive confirmation code in activity A. there is one method in both activity which is common between them and I'm using this method to trig child class when a specific event happens.  [sectionRequestDone()]

```
public class A extends ActivityEnhanced {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a);
....

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = username.getText().toString();
                    String pwd = password.getText().toString();
                    login(userInfo); // this method is in parent class
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void sectionRequestDone() {
        goToActivity();
    }

    private void goToActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Class B;

```
public class B extends ActivityEnhanced {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.b);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clearSections();
                sectionRequest();
            }
        });

        fillAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public void sectionRequestDone() {
        fillAdapter();
        alphaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

now he question is, whenever I click on btn in class B method sectionRequestDone() in class A is calling but I want it works in class B. This is so weird because I finished class A. Is there any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't provide full code. Where are  `clearSections()` and `sectionRequest()`?

Comment: Your use of static fields in `ActivityEnhanced` is highly suspicious.

Comment: @mTak these two methods are n parent, I meant in ActivityEnhanced

Comment: @Henry this two fields are static because I want to save socket and data for all sub classes

Comment: `public static INetConnection mNetWork;
    private static DataPacket dataPacket;`. Remove the static. This has been suggested before.

Comment: You say "whenever I click on btn in class B method sectionRequestDone() in class A is calling". How have you determined this is what is happening? Does it re-launch Activity B then? `sectionRequestDone` in Activity A should launch Activity B

Comment: @Tyler V if I delete (return;) from goToActivity() method it will relaunch activity B

Comment: @greenapps I will remove  static but it doesn't refer to the problem. If i don't use static field I have to connect to socket in every activity

Comment: I don't see a `return` in the `goToActivity()` you posted... I'd suggest adding some log outputs in those functions to verify that it is in fact doing what you think it is doing. Based on the code you posted, there's no way that B could be calling an overridden method in A.

Comment: @MohsenHatami You're referring to code that does not exist. If you don't provide full code of the 3 activities how do you expect help?

Comment: @Tyler V Thanks for your help, I found the problem and I will share it with you, Thanks

Comment: @mTak Thanks for your help, I found the problem and I will share it with you, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have to thanks all who helped me. After a few hours I've found the solution.

**Solution:**

If I want to use an activity as a parent in which there are some static fields, I have to set their listeners in every activity which means that I have to do that in onResume() method in ActivityEnhanced class. In the previous code all listeners for INetConnection called just in class A and these listeners didn't called again in class B so when sectionRequestDone() method called it trigged in class A not B.

I removed (implements INetConnection.Callback) from ActivityEnhanced and changed the code like this:

```
public class ActivityEnhanced extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static INetConnection mNetWork;
    private static DataPacket dataPacket;


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        G.setCurrentActivity(this);

        if(dataPacket == null){
            dataPacket = new DataPacket();
        }

        if(mNetWork == null){
            mNetWork = new INetConnection(this);
            mNetWork.connectToNetwork();
        }else{
            mNetWork.setOnCallbackListener(new INetConnection.Callback(){
                @Override
                public void onSocketNull() {}

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuccessful() {}

                @Override
                public void onDataReceive(Byte[] data) {
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    sectionRequestDone();
                }
            );
        }
    }
    .....
    .
    .
    public void sectionRequestDone() {}
}
```